# SQL Show not duplicates lines LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates, left-join

What I want to do is match lines against each other and exclude all lines that matches more than one time.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87dc5/1)

Data set (keep in mind that this is simplified and there's a lot more information I need to retrieve from query)

**Table 1:**

```
NAME    PART1       PART2

ABC     FirstABC    SecondABC
BAC     FirstBAC    SecondBAC
BAC     SecondBAC   FirstBAC
CBA     FirstCBA    SecondCBA
DAE     FirstDAE    SecondDAE
EDA     FirstEDA    SecondEDA
```

**Table 2:**

```
ITEM1       ITEM2

FirstABC    SecondABC
FirstBAC    SecondBAC
FirstBAC    SecondBAC
FirstCBA    SecondCBA
FirstDAE    SecondDAE
FirstEDA    SecondEDA
```

What I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM TOMATCH as T
LEFT JOIN AGAINST as A
ON (
  T.Part1 = A.Item1
  OR T.Part2 = A.Item1
  OR T.Part1 = A.Item2
  OR T.Part2 = A.Item2
  )
```

What result I'm looking for:

```
NAME    PART1       PART2       ITEM1       ITEM2

ABC     FirstABC    SecondABC   FirstABC    SecondABC
CBA     FirstCBA    SecondCBA   FirstCBA    SecondCBA
DAE     FirstDAE    SecondDAE   FirstDAE    SecondDAE
EDA     FirstEDA    SecondEDA   FirstEDA    SecondEDA
```

Comment: What about SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: The desired result is not clear. What are duplicates? Use `DISTINCT` and you get [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87dc5/4/0) result which is different. **Edit** Do you have primary-keys?

Comment: the wanted result is to exclude results WITH duplicates (if I understodd well). Distinct will avoid duplicates, but show datas "which would be duplicated without distinct".

Comment: @ClaasWilke no I don't want to use `DISTINCT`. I want to exclude completely that row as you can see in result I'm looking for.

Comment: @skmasq could you just add, in your sample, one or two columns which would not be part of the matching ? And show desired result ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus here you go http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1988/1 , I want to update `UniqueMatch` with `ItemNumber` that's why I can't have duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just group by all fields, and add an having clause with count = 1.

```
SELECT name, part1, part2, item1, item2
FROM TOMATCH as T
LEFT JOIN AGAINST as A
ON (
 T.Part1 = A.Item1
 OR T.Part2 = A.Item1
 OR T.Part1 = A.Item2
 OR T.Part2 = A.Item2
 )
group by name, part1, part2, item1, item2
having count(*) = 1
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87dc5/10)

Comment: But does not exactly what OP wants, i assume he wants to find all rows which don't match the `ON` clause twice. The sample data is not optimal.

Comment: @TimSchmelter well, desired result seems to look like my result... (and that's what I understood, which may be wrong, of course)

Comment: @TimSchmelter is right. As I mentioned this is simplified version of data set, actually there are 20 columns but only 4 columns does the matching.

Comment: @skmasq well, then a join on this as a subquery should be fine.

Comment: @skmasq: You could use a `NOT EXISTS` on the condition in the `ON`. But it's difficult to differentiate between the rows without PK's.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I use this with `NOT IN` clause and then do another match without `GROUP BY`. But the query gets really big and I just wondered is there much simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the duplicates out of AGAINST before joining to TOMATCH.

```
UPDATE t
  SET UniqueMatch = ItemNumber
FROM TOMATCH t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Item1, Item2, MIN(ItemNumber) AS ItemNumber
  FROM AGAINST
  GROUP BY Item1, Item2
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) a ON (Item1 = Part1 AND Item2 = Part2)
```